# Trying to display components with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use React hooks to display a component when a button is pressed. I'm sure this is some simple syntax wrong here. Any guidance?

```
const [displayComponent, setDisplayComponent] = useState(null);

    function sendComponent() {
      setDisplayComponent(
      displayComponent = {<TheImportedComponentIWantToDisplay/>}
      )
    }

    return (

        <Button  onClick={sendComponent} >Push to render component</Button>

        {displayComponent}
)
```

Comment: Please give a [mre]. But yes, syntax errors (you can't put a JSX element in an object), JSX errors (you can't return multiple elements like that, use a fragment) and hook errors (you're not using the setter).

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said, you have some errors. here is the fixed version : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8trcti?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: @yaya Thank you so much. For my own understanding, I was under the impression I had to set displayComponent to something, as it's the current value- which is why I had it nested and set that to my component.

Your example works great but how does it know what displayComponent is since it appears you just set setDisplayComponent to it? I just want to understand the why. Thanks!

Comment: @AlvinRumption i'm not sure if i get what you mean, but if you mean: "when we write: `setDisplayComponent(<Comp1 />)`, how `displayComponent` will be equal to : `<Comp1 />` ? " then the answer is: `setDisplayComponent` is a setter function for `displayComponent`. it means it will set `displayComponent` to the value you pass to it, and it does some other stuffs (re-rendering the component.). you should use setter functions (like : `setDisplayComponent(value)`) to change the state variable (`displayComponent`) in a functional component.

Comment: @yaya That was exactly my question. Thank you so much again.